# Подсветка ключевых слов match-case в Python

Tags: дефект, markdown, подсветка-синтаксиса

Возьмём такой код (взят из документации):

```python
def http_error(status):
    match status:
        case 400:
            return "Bad request"
        case 404:
            return "Not found"
        case 418:
            return "I'm a teapot"
        case _:
            return "Something's wrong with the internet"
```

Как видно, ключевые слова `match` и `case` не подсвечиваются синим.

Следует учесть, что `match` и `case` - это мягкие ключевые слова, т. е. в примере выше они должны подсвечиваться, а вот тут нет:

```python
match = re.match(r'\b', 'hello123')
```

[Здесь](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/) и [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching) можно почитать подробно про `match` и `case`.

Comment: Когда-нибудь версию зависимости highlight.js обновят и все заработает (актуальная версия умеет подсвечивать match/case).